# HY000/1049 Unknown database when using mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","shoutit", "80");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

When I try to run this I get the error message of

> Unknown database.

How come something off the official documentation doesn't work? I couldn't find a solution for this. Adding an "80" port makes it load forever.

Comment: Port `80` is normally for an HTTP server, not MySQL. The usual port for MySQL is 3306.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you don't have a database named `shoutit`.

Comment: Looks like you are right, but changing it to 3306 gives the same error. And yes I have the database called that.

Comment: On Unix, database names are case sensitive. Are you sure you got the case correct?

Comment: yes. even if i try to connect to default database like "host" it will still not work

Comment: There's no default database named `host`. Are you sure you're not confusing database and table names?

Comment: Turns out I did! and I found my problem! Thank you so much @Bar

Comment: Hello cyrstyxn. Why don't you publish the answer so any user with similar problem can reach the solution?